# Use gurnt-connect-proxy proxy to cloudfront get 403 error

Tags: javascript, proxy, gruntjs, amazon-cloudfront

I use `grunt-connect-proxy` to reverse proxy some page to my CloudFront website, but it can't work.

ENV:

- grunt: `^0.4.5`
- grunt-contrib-connect: `^0.9.0`,
- grunt-connect-proxy: `^0.2.0`,

**What I tried**

1. Use `http-proxy`(*Success*):

```
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target: {
  protocol: 'http:',
  host: 'myhostname.com',
  port: 80,
},
headers: {
  host: 'myhostname.com'
}}).listen(8080)
```

2. Use `curl` (*Success*):

```
curl -v http://myhostname.com/signin
```

3. Use `Nginx` (*Success*):

```
location ~* ^/(signin|styles|scripts) {
  proxy_pass http://myhostname.com;
}
```

**Use `grunt-connect-proxy` Failded**

```
connect: {
  server: {
    options: {
      open: true,
        base: ['app'],
          middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
            if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
              options.base = [options.base];
            }
            middlewares.push(modRewrite([
              '^\\/customer-portal\\/((?!\\.).)*$ /index.html'
            ]));
            middlewares.push(connect.static(options.base[0]));
            middlewares.push(require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest)
            return middlewares;
          }
    },
    proxies: [{
      context: ['/signin', '/scripts', '/styles'],
      host: 'myhostname.com',
      port: '80',
      https: false,
    }]
  },
}
```

It gets 403 code from CloudFront (I'm not sure 403 in CloudFront is 404 or no). 
if I add `headers` to `proxies`

```
proxies: [{
 ...
  headers: {
    'host': 'myhostname.com'
  }
 ...
}]
```

I get `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` error from chrome.
So, what's the correct configuration??

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with a customer middleware via `http-proxy`, have given up to use `grunt-connect-proxy`, code like this:

```
middlewares.push(function(req, res, next) {
  if(someRegex.test(req.url) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {target: 'myhostname.com'})
  } else {
    return next();
  }
})
```